# Codeigniter form builder csrf 500 server error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I am integrating this form builder ([shlomnissan/formbuilder](https://github.com/shlomnissan/formbuilder)) into Codeigniter and am getting a 500 server error when trying to save the form.

I am passing the CSRF token name and value (I have logged these to the console to confirm they exist)

Normally I would use PHP to echo the values to the ajax form post, but the javascript is in a separate JS file.

The code to call the formbuilder function is as follows:

```
$('#form-builder').formBuilder({
      load_url: '/formbuilder/get_form_template',
      save_url: '/formbuilder/save_form',
      csrf_name: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>',
      csrf_token: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
    });
```

I have changed the code, in the formBuilder.js file as follows, but this gives me an "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" error:

```
$('#save').click(function(e){

                    var form_data = serialize();
                    var csrf_name = settings.csrf_name;
                    var csrf_token = settings.csrf_token;

                    $.ajax({

                        type: "POST",
                        url: settings.save_url,
                        data: {formData: form_data, csrf_name: csrf_token},

                        success: function () {
                            settings.onSaveForm.call();
                        }

                    });
```

I have also set the values to be included in the form_data variable before it is serialized :

```
var serialize = function() {

        var formData = {};

        formData['title']       = $('#form-title').val();
        formData['description'] = $('#form-description').val();

        var csrf_token = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');
        formData['csrf_token_name'] = csrf_token;
```

some code removed from above for brevity.

Once the form is submitted, I receive a 500 internal server error; the form data being passed is as follows:

```
{"title":"My Form","description":"This is my form. Please fill it out. It's awesome!","csrf_token_name":"bcf43ac1ca40e9d0fa8d1c6d6da9f34b","fields":[{"title":"First Name","type":"element-single-line-text","required":true,"position":1},{"title":"Last Name","type":"element-single-line-text","required":true,"position":2},{"title":"Email","type":"element-single-line-text","required":true,"position":3}]}
```

If you need to see any more code, please let me know.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 500 errors when doing ajax calls usually means there's some error in the PHP code.

Comment: Hi, there's not much PHP going on to be honest except for echoing out the CSRF token and name; this is being passed to the js file fine. I am trying to echo out the $_POST data after the form is submitted, but it does not get that far.

Comment: Hi NealH , same problem for me. If you get the solution for solving this issue, please add here. thanks

Comment: @shijinmonPallikal I changed `var csrf_name = settings.csrf_name;` to `var csrf_name = "csrf_token_name"` in the formBuilder.js file. Check the CI config file for the actual name of csrf_token_name as yours may be different.